# Média de idade em uma família - Core dump error

Tags: c, compilação

o código abaixo tem a intenção de ler uma quantidade qtd de pessoas em uma família, receber a soma das idades e apresentar a média ao final:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int qtd, idade, i;
    float soma=0 , media;

    printf("Informe quantos membros há na família: ");
    scanf("%d\n", qtd);

        do{

            printf("informe a idade: ");
            scanf("%d\n", idade);

            soma += idade;
            i++;

        }while(i<= qtd);

        media = soma / qtd;
        printf("a média de idade da família é: %f\n",media);

    return 0;
}
```

Ocorre segmentation fault (algumas vezes seguido de core dump) assim que ele faz a letura de `qtd`

não intendo qual violação de acesso cometi no código acima.

Comment: onde está a inicialização de "i" ?
mas o erro é aqui: "scanf("%d\n", qtd);" ---> scanf("%d\n", &qtd);"

Comment: Quando você deseja fazer uma leitura de um valor escalar, os argumentos após a string de formato devem ser ponteiros

Comment: @zentrunix a inicialização da variavel no escopo global nao deu nenhum diferença (i=0). De fato, esqueci o '&' mas , mesmo assim, após a leitura de qtd ele aguarda a entrada de mais alguma coisa e só depois entra no laço while. Por fim ou gera um valor incorreto ou... segmentation fault.

Comment: e onde está o "&" no scanf de "idade" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está faltando algumas correções de sintaxe em seu código.
Por exemplo não é necessário colocar `\n` no seu `scanf`, após a leitura ele já dá um `\n` automático, e outra que você esqueceu de por o `&` antes da variável que receberá o valor, e seguindo a lógica do seu `do-while` você iria ler uma idade a mais.
no fim o código com essas pequenas alterações ficaria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int qtd, idade, i=0;
    float soma=0 , media;

    printf("Informe quantos membros há na família: ");
    scanf("%d", &qtd);

        do{

            printf("informe a idade: ");
            scanf("%d", &idade);

            soma += idade;
            i++;

        }while(i< qtd);

        media = soma / qtd;
        printf("a média de idade da família é: %f\n", media);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Faltou inicializar a variável média e colocar `&` nos scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int qtd, idade, i;
    float soma=0 , media=0;

    printf("Informe quantos membros há na família: ");
    scanf("%d\n",&qtd);

        do{

            printf("informe a idade: ");
            scanf("%d\n",&idade);

            soma += idade;
            i++;

        }while(i<= qtd);

        media = soma / qtd;
        printf("a média de idade da família é: %f\n",media);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exatamente pessoal. Cometi erros triviais como a ausência do '&'...

Só não me ficou claro exatamente por que razão ele dava ***segmentation fault*** ao aplicar (desnecessariamente. Erro meu) "\n" ao ler qtd.

De qualquer forma, seguindo a orientação dos colegas cheguei ao resultado que queria.

OBS: `while(i < qtd)` é a lógica correta. Obrigado!

int main()
    {

```
    int qtd,  i=0;
    float soma=0 , media, idade;

    printf("Informe quantos membros há na família: ");
    scanf("%d", &qtd);

        do{

            printf("informe a idade: ");
            scanf("%f", &idade);

            soma += idade;
            i++;

        }while(i < qtd);

        media = soma / qtd;
        printf("a média de idade da família é: %f\n", media);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dava erro porque a função scanf espera receber como parâmetro o endereço da variável que receberá o conteúdo lido e você estava passando como endereço o conteúdo da variável que, neste caso, era lixo de memória e provavelmente indicando um endereço fora do espaço endereçável de seu programa.